# How to include a JS file into and Angular 2 project?

Tags: angular, odoo

I want to include this JS file into my angular 2 project in order to connect it with odoo :

I installed it with : npm install --save odoo-connect and this is the script. Any ideas of how to do that ? thank you

```
const Odoo = require('odoo-connect');

const odoo = new Odoo({
    host: 'foobar.com',
    port: 9999
});

odoo
    .connect({
        database: 'unicorn',
        username: 'foo',
        password: 'bar'
    })
    .then(client => {
        return client.searchRead('product.product', [['list_price', '>', '50']], {limit: 1});
    })
    .then(products => {
        console.log(products);
        //=> [{list_price: 52, name: 'Unicorn'}] 
    });
```

Comment: use systemjs or webpack and add it to your index.html.

Comment: @luukgruijs can you please elaborate ? I m still a beginner at this , and I m not sure I got your point